# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I get this error message: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSManagedObjectContext ".

I am not sure how to fix this error. The error is with the "if let" I think.

```
  if  let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext  {
        restaurant = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Restaurant",
            inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Restaurant
        restaurant.name = nameTextField.text
        restaurant.type = typeTextField.text
        restaurant.location = locationTextField.text
        restaurant.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)
        restaurant.isVisited = isVisited
        //restaurant.isVisited = NSNumber.convertFromBooleanLiteral(isVisited)

        var e: NSError?
        if managedObjectContext.save() != true {
            print("insert error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to force downcast (`as!`), then you don't need to use the optional binding (`if let`) because your app delegate will be force unwrapped.  If `managedObjectContext` is non optional, then it can't be unwrapped, which is what the compiler is saying.  But if you want to unwrap it safely in an optional binding (`if let`), you can achieve this with a condition downcast (`as?`) and optional chaining (`?.`):

```
if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
    // Do something with managedObjectContext...
}
```